# How to prevent edge labels from messing up the layout in graphviz?

Tags: label, graph-theory, graphviz, dot, edge-list

I have a simple vertical graph that looks nice and symmetrical without any labels using the following code:

```
digraph test_alignment
{
    {rank=same; a -> b;}
    a -> c;
    b -> c;
    c -> d;
    d -> e;
    d -> f;
    {rank=same; e -> f;}
}
```

[image: The initial graph]

I'd like to label the edge between A and B as well as the one between E and F, using the same string for each label. I'm expecting the same output, except with longer A->B and E->F edges bearing the same label.

Unfortunately, as soon as I add a label to one of these edges, the general layout looks slightly askew (the result is similar if I add a label to the E->F edge):

```
digraph test_alignment
{
    {rank=same; a -> b [label="Label"];}
    a -> c;
    b -> c;
    c -> d;
    d -> e;
    d -> f;
    {rank=same; e -> f;}
}
```

[image: The same graph with one label]

I'm very new to graphviz and, following many questions on Stack Overflow, I have been experimenting with different combinations of rank and constraint, I tried using clusters to see if it would keep the top and bottom part properly aligned independently, and tried using a mix of dot, ccomp, gvpack and neato that produced similar results.

It always seems to boil down to the fact adding a label to the edge between nodes with the same rank affects how these nodes are positioned in a way I don't yet understand.

Am I missing something trivial, or am I attempting something I shouldn't instead of letting dot do its thing?

I'm using dot - graphviz version 2.36.0 (20140111.2315) and the linked pictures were produced with dot only (though I obtained similar results when using :

```
dot test_alignment.dot -Tpng -O
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try to use the [`xlabel`](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:xlabel) attribute, together with `forcelabels` if necessary. From the description:

> ... For edges, the label will be placed near the center of the edge. This
>   can be useful in dot to avoid the occasional problem when the use of
>   edge labels distorts the layout. ...

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe I missed the xlabel attribute, thank you so much. I managed to achieve the result I wanted using a mix of xlabel, minlen and (admittedly slightly ugly) HTML label.

Thank you!